# Formatting money values without decimals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Item   Price
0   A      1761284
1   B      300768
2   C      531062
3   D      69937
4   E      19200
```

And I need to convert the price column to float, this step is easy, but I also need to consider the last 2 characters as cents:

```
    Item   Price
0   A      17612.84
1   B      3007.68
2   C      5310.62
3   D      699.37
4   E      192.00
```

I've searched for a workaround for this issue but haven't found anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Divide your values by 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use :

```py
>>> df['Price'] / 100
```

### Detail

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'], 
...                    'Price': [1761284, 300768, 531062, 69937, 19200]}, 
...                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> df
    Item    Price
0   A       1761284
1   B       300768
2   C       531062
3   D       69937
4   E       19200
```

We can divide the column `Price` by 100 to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['Price'] = df['Price'] / 100
>>> df
    Item    Price
0   A       17612.84
1   B       3007.68
2   C       5310.62
3   D       699.37
4   E       192.00
```

### Bonus

We can even make it fancy and format the column `Price` by adding the currency like so :

```py
>>> df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x: f"${x:.2f}")
    Item    Price       Price_with_currency
0   A       17612.84    $17612.84
1   B       3007.68     $3007.68
2   C       5310.62     $5310.62
3   D       699.37      $699.37
4   E       192.00      $192.00
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df['NewPrice'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['Amount'] / 100, axis=1)
```

Comment: Lambda is not needed to use here. We can divide all elements of series by 100 without iteration. There is also not a column 'Amount' in the dataframe and there is no need to create a column 'NewPrice' as overwriting the values is expected here.